# Storing custom properties for a SharePoint Site

Tags: best-practices, spweb, development

Let's say you are building a Project Management solution where each Project equals one site (SPWeb object). Each project has it's properties like: Project Manager, Budget, Customer, Description, Status etc... that need to be stored. Beside these, site contains other project items like documents, tasks etc...

What do you think would be the best practice to store these, some options I am considering, but I am open to suggestions here:

- Custom list on this site (**PROS**:
  Easy to edit, **CONS**: data is not
  uniform for single list)
- Embedded into SPWeb.Properties
  (**PROS**: Easy to develop with,
  **CONS**: No built-in user UI and other SharePoint UI benefits)
- Custom list(s) on root of this site
  collection (**PROS**: Centralized,
  **CONS**: Requires custom per-project security to implement)
- Custom Database (**PROS**:
  Relational, **CONS**: No SharePoint
  benefits here...)

Comment: Good Pro's and con's!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a similarly structured project management solution in a previous life and used a list to store those details, the list only contained one item, and the columns were the project's metadata.

Worked quite well for rollup across all the projects to get details for all.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done before as well and agree that it worked out really well.

Comment: Interesting, two questions: 1) What if there are too many columns? 2) How did you aggregate all these on Project Portfolio level?

Comment: I had a site (SPWeb) in which all projects (each of which an SPWeb) resided, and I used a simple DataViewWebPart which used recursion to extract a particular content type (the list details).

Doesn't matter how many columns there are, you pick and choose using a View.

Comment: I am trying to do same thing, I have list item with a column "Status" in every project with value either "won" or "lost" and I want to show list of all project either won or lost, any idea how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides some guidance in this area.

[SharePoint patterns & practices Application Settings Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://spconfigstore.codeplex.com/ . There is a config category column that can relate to the Project  This is a 2007 solution